# java: display the elements from a database

Tags: java, sql

I wrote some java code to display database,  when I run the code it gives me just the last  element of database , but I wanna  display all elements of table

the code :

```
public String RecupererPuissance() {
    try {
        Connection con =  myDbvoiture.getConnection();
        String queryPattern ="select Power from bd_voiture";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =  con.prepareStatement(queryPattern);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            puissance=rs.getString("Power");
            System.out.println(puissance);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return puissance;
}
```

What should I do? Can anyone please help me to display all values?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Your code looks correct. How many elements are inside the table bd_voiture? Also, how many elements inside the Resultset `rs`? Also, try to pass an `order by` clause to that `select`, so you get predictable results (`select` get unordered results by default)

Comment: @DiegoFreniche thank you for your help, I have 40 elements in my table , but one  element inside the Resultset.

Comment: Do you get all 40 elements printed by that `println`? Also, look [JHead answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37457343/225503)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your code that the value of `puissance` is overwritten every time you get the next element. Only the last value is returned. You should put the results into a list and return the whole list:

```
public List<String> RecupererPuissance() {
    List<String> puissances = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Connection con =  myDbvoiture.getConnection();
        String queryPattern ="select Power from bd_voiture";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =  con.prepareStatement(queryPattern);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            puissance = rs.getString("Power");
            puissances.add(puissance);
            System.out.println(puissance);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return puissances;
}
```

Comment: You need to correct the following lines:
`puissances.add(rs.getString("Power"));
            System.out.println(puissance);` to be `puissance = rs.getString("Power"); puissances.add(puissance);
            System.out.println(puissance);`

At the moment, your `puissance` isn't being set, which could cause issues at the print line statement

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this matter, I did that but nothing has changed , i don't understand why?

Comment: @Draken when i change my code and call my web service  i used this code ` mws.MyWebService_Service service = new mws.MyWebService_Service();
        mws.MyWebService port = service.getMyWebServicePort();
      String puis= port.recupererPuissance();
         System.out.println(puis); ` do you think the problem is in this a part

Comment: It is, it should be:
`List<String> puisList= port.recupererPuissance();` instead of `String puis= port.recupererPuissance();`

Then you could iterate it using a `for` loop, as an example. So if you want to print it, it would be:
`for(String puis : puisList) System.out.println(puis);`

Comment: @Draken Great, My code is working , thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String RecupererPuissance() {
    try {
        Connection con =  myDbvoiture.getConnection();
        String queryPattern ="select Power from bd_voiture";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =  con.prepareStatement(queryPattern);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        rs.first();
        int count=0;
        while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("count = "+count);
        count+=1;
            puissance=rs.getString("Power");
            System.out.println(puissance);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return puissance;
}
```

If you see count printed only 1 time :

it would mean that you have only 1 row in column Power
and you maybe referring to the wrong column in your code

Comment: thank you for your help, I did that   but nothing has changed